# Spring boot project not running in Intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to run basic spring boot app in IntelliJ. I get the below error and the project automatically stops running.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at com.shivam.org.myapp.MyappApplication.main(MyappApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 1 more
```

As per [this](https://mkyong.com/maven/maven-error-invalid-target-release-17/) link I fixed my `JAVA_HOME` value to JDK 17 and I am able to run it from terminal in IntelliJ using command `mvn spring-boot:run` but when I right click and run the `Application.java` of my project I get the above exception. I have also tried deleting the repository folder content in `.m2` directory, restarted IntelliJ but it fails to run. Also I generated this project from [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) and imported in IntelliJ it was running fine, today I just added actuator and devtools in pom.xml and started facing this issue. I removed the dependencies and still not fixed. I am using spring boot 3.0.6 and Java 17.

Maven dependency tree

```
PS C:\Users\shiva\Documents\spring-projects\myapp\myapp> mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.shivam.org:myapp >------------------------
[INFO] Building myapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:tree (default-cli) @ myapp ---
[INFO] com.shivam.org:myapp:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.19.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.19.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.14.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.14.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.14.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.14.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.14.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.14.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.8:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.8:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.10.6:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.10.6:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.0.8:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.8:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.8:provided
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.8:provided
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.0.6:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.0.6:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.6:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.10:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.9:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.3:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.7:provided
[INFO]    +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.23.1:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.23:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.9.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.2:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.2:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.2:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.2:test
[INFO]    |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.23:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.8:provided
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.8:provided
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.0.8:test
[INFO]    \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.678 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-22T19:43:10+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS C:\Users\shiva\Documents\spring-projects\myapp\myapp>
```

Comment: Start over with the initializer and get it to build and run from the command line.  Do not involve any ide before that works.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen this already seems to work "I am able to run it from terminal in IntelliJ using command mvn spring-boot:run"

Comment: Try to remove the .idea folder from the project directory and start IntelliJ again

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Deleted .idea folder after closing the project, imported again , rebuild and still the issue persists.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I didn't read it that way - my bad probably.  The error message shows that the classpath does not contain the spring libraries which hints that IntelliJ for some reason is confused.  When this happens I remove the folder completely, reclone it from whereever it is put in git, and tell IntelliJ to open the folder.  This essentially resets everything.

Comment: Do you have **Add Dependencies with provided scope to classpath** option set in Run/Debug Configuration: https://imgur.com/izg9dsc.png ?

Comment: Can you provide this project to check?

Comment: @Andrey I would provide it but I deleted the extracted project as I had zip file, after extracting again and importing it's working fine now. If you still need it let me know. I added the dev tool and actuator dependency from maven in IntelliJ and it caused the issue but this time I copied dependency from exploring pom.xml at start.spring.io and it worked fine. Still not sure what caused it.

Comment: @Andrey Also I do not have the option  *Add Dependencies with provided scope to classpath* set in IntelliJ